# How to organize data that alternates between negative and positive values in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of data points in a file that I am inserting into a linked list class that I built.
The file is organized such that there are a series of negative values followed by a series of positive values alternating back and forth.
An example:

```
-2323 

-2324

-53434

-1027

-34232

 343434

 5657

 6565

 6500

-343434

-3434

-565

5845

4667

5453

98356
```

This pattern continues for many lines.  The number of negative or positive values is never the same for each section.

I would like to separate these values somehow so that the first list object contains the first set of positive to negative numbers, in this case from `-2323` to `6500`.  The next list object would contain the values from `-343434` to `98356`, and so on.

I cannot figure out how to get python to know how to separate these sets of data when reading the file.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What happens if it goes, neg, 0, neg, pos?  is that one dataset or two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def takeSection(sequence):
    it = iter(sequence)
    a = -1
    group = []
    while True:
        try:
            a, last = next(it), a
        except StopIteration:
            if group:
                yield group
            return
        if a < 0 and last >= 0:
            if group:
                yield group
            group = [a]
        else:
            group.append(a)
```

---

```
>>> sequence = [-2323, -2324, -53434, -1027, -34232, 343434, 5657, 6565, 6500, -343434, -3434, -565, 5845, 4667, 5453, 98356]
>>> list(takeSection(sequence))
Out[2]: 
[[-2323, -2324, -53434, -1027, -34232, 343434, 5657, 6565, 6500],
 [-343434, -3434, -565, 5845, 4667, 5453, 98356]]
```

### Edit

If you want to filter this on the first value in a pair of values, you can change the if condition to test for this instead. You could for instance change the condition line to `if a[0] < 0 and last[0] >=0`, and you'd also need to initialise `a` as `a = (-1, -1)`

However I'd be tempted to make a more generalised and useful function instead.

```
def sections(sequence, key):
    it = iter(sequence)
    a = placeholder = object()
    group = []
    while True:
        try:
            a, last = next(it), a
        except StopIteration:
            if group:
                yield group
            return
        if last is not placeholder and key(a, last):
            if group:
                yield group
            group = [a]
        else:
            group.append(a)
```

---

```
>>> sequence = [(-2323, -7465), (-2324, -7687), (-53434, -1027), (-34232, 343434), (5657, 6565), (6500, 978987), (-343434, -987), (-3434, -565), (-98, -8798), (-89898, -898), (5845, 4667), (5453, 98356)]
>>> list(sections(sequence, key=lambda current, last: current[0] < 0 and last[0] >= 0))
Out[1]:
[[(-2323, -7465), (-2324, -7687), (-53434, -1027), (-34232, 343434), (5657, 6565), (6500, 978987)],
 [(-343434, -987), (-3434, -565), (-98, -8798), (-89898, -898), (5845, 4667), (5453, 98356)]]
```

Comment: Thank you, this code works correctly

However, what if sequence is in the format of (x,y) points?
For example:
sequence = [(-2323, -7465), (-2324, -7687), (-53434, -1027), (-34232, 343434), (5657, 6565), (6500, 978987) (-343434, -987) (-3434, -565), (-98, -8798), (-89898, -898), (5845, 4667), (5453, 98356)]
Each section would still be organized based on the negative/positive first value (the x value) in each point.
Sorry for the change from the original question, but when I tried to apply your answer to this case, I could not get it to work correctly.

Answer (score 4):

```
import itertools
groups = itertools.groupby(l, lambda x : x > 0)
result = [list(groups[i][1]) + list(groups[i + 1][1]) for i in range(0, len(groups), 2)]
```

This will first group the elements by whether they are positive or not, and will then combine adjacent pairs from the groups into a single list, which will then be an element of the result list.

Edit: I keep forgetting that itertools makes objects that don't work like normal iterables.

The following should actually work, if a bit more messily.

```
import itertools
groups = itertools.groupby(l, lambda x : x > 0)
grouplist = [[i for i in y] for (x, y) in groups]
result = [grouplist[i] + grouplist[i + 1] for i in range(0, len(grouplist), 2)]
```

Comment: I like this solution, but wont it get `IndexError` for when `grouplist` is an odd length? Maybe better to pass the same instance of `iter(grouplist)` into `izip_longest(iter_grouplist, iter_grouplist, fillvalue=[])`?

Comment: I was sort of trying to avoid using itertools objects more than necessary. Either that would work, or it could be done by inserting a line between the last two lines setting grouplist = grouplist + [[]] if len(grouplist) % 2 else grouplist.